# SQL Server : manipulating complex xml into tables

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have some XML which I need to insert into two database tables. The second table (`TblSales`) must contain the PK of the first (`TblDetails.Id`).

I can insert the data into these tables using XQuery, but I cannot think of a good way to get the PK of `TblDetails` into FK (`DetailsId`) of `TblSales`?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 
N'<Details>
    <Detail>
        <Sub>SubjectName 1</Sub>
        <Data>DataName 1</Data>
        <Sales>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 1</Name>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 11</Name>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 111</Name>
            </Sale>
        </Sales>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <Sub>SubjectName 2</Sub>
        <Data>DataName 2</Data>
        <Sales>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 2</Name>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 22</Name>
            </Sale>
            <Sale>
                <Name>Name 222</Name>
            </Sale>
        </Sales>
    </Detail>
</Details>'

-- Details

IF object_id('TblDetails') is not null
    drop table TblDetails

create table TblDetails ( 
    Id int identity not null primary key, 
    Sub nvarchar(max),
    Data nvarchar(max)) 

INSERT INTO TblDetails (
    Sub, 
    Data
)
SELECT
    ParamValues.Detail.value('(Sub)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Sub],
    ParamValues.Detail.value('(Data)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Data]
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Details/Detail') AS ParamValues(Detail)


-- Sales

IF object_id('TblSales') is not null
    drop table TblSales

create table TblSales ( 
    Id int identity not null primary key, 
    Name nvarchar(max),
    DetailsId int) -- FK to TblDetails.Id PK

INSERT INTO TblSales (
    Name, 
    DetailsId
)
SELECT
    ParamValues.Sale.value('(Name)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Name],
    1 --Need to get the PK of the newly added row in TblDetails
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Details/Detail/Sales/Sale') AS ParamValues(Sale)



select * from TblDetails
select * from TblSales
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
-- first insert your rows into "TblDetails"
INSERT INTO dbo.TblDetails(Sub, Data)
   SELECT
      ParamValues.Detail.value('(Sub)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS [Sub],
      ParamValues.Detail.value('(Data)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS [Data]
   FROM 
      @xml.nodes('/Details/Detail') AS ParamValues(Detail)

-- now, in a second step, use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to get the
-- inserted data and the new data for TblSales
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        ParamValues.Detail.value('(Sub)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS [Sub],
        ParamValues.Detail.value('(Data)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS [Data],
        XTbl.Sale.value('(Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Name]
    FROM 
        @xml.nodes('/Details/Detail') AS ParamValues(Detail)
    CROSS APPLY
        ParamValues.Detail.nodes('Sales/Sale') AS XTbl(Sale)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TblSales(Name, DetailsId)
   SELECT 
      Name,
      (SELECT TOP  1 ID    -- fetch the ID from the TblDetails based on "Sub" and "Data"
       FROM TblDetails d 
       WHERE d.Sub = CTE.Sub AND d.Data = CTE.DATA)     
   FROM CTE
```

Of course, this approach only really works if your combinations of (`Sub, Data`) are unique in the `TblDetails`. Maybe you need to tweak this a bit - but it should be a good startig point, I hope!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately data within TblDetails cannot be guaranteed to be unique. Is this the common technique used for doing this type of procedure? Another option is to add an additional column to the table 'TblSales' that will store the 'SalesXml' data. Then when the 'Insert' on 'TblDetails' occurs I can 'OUTPUT' the 'INSERTED TblDetails.Id' and 'INSERTED TblDetails.SalesXml' into a temporary table. But this is adding additional data to the table that is only needed for this procedure.

Comment: @DanielBillingham: if your (`Sub,Data`) cannot be unique - then you must have something else in the source XML by which you can **uniquely identify** a `<Detail>` node - otherwise this will never work ...